# Ruby iterate over all model objects, manipulate each and add to CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, enumeration

I need to iterate over all objects of the `Client` model, do some manipulation in order to get an array, then append this array to a CSV file.

I have a `get` method which does the object iteration and returns an array:

```
def get
  Client.find_each do |client|
    [client.id, client.name] # How do I return one array at a time?
  end
end
```

Then I have the actual CSV generation method:

```
def generate
  CSV.open('file', 'w') do |csv|
    csv << # How do I get one array at a time from the above get?
  end
end
```

I can call `get` in `generate` and iterate over all resulted arrays, but that would kill performance. How can I use an array at a time inside `generate`, as returned by `get`?

I believe enumerators could help here, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby blocks come to the rescue:

```
def get
  raise 'Block required' unless block_given?
  Client.find_each do |client|
    yield [client.id, client.name] # this will be yielded on each iteration
  end
end

def generate
  CSV.open('file', 'w') do |csv|
    get do |id, name|
      csv << [id, name] # this will be called on each `find_each` from above
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: And is there a solution without blocks? I was thinking of "asking" `get` for the next array, instead of your current solution where `get` gives you an array? Is it possible to do something like `csv << get.next`?

Comment: Probably it’s possible, but I won’t help to turn ruby into php. Blocks are invented for that.

Comment: You're right. I know that if you call certain methods you get an enumerator (like `each`). Then you get the next values using `.next`. That's why I've asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Enumerator`:

```
def get
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    Client.find_each do |client|
      yielder.yield [client.id, client.name]
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your CSV generate method you can use `client_enumerator = get` and iterate with `client_enumerator.next` to get one array at a time.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for this solution as well!

Comment: This in fact will construct an array of size of original table.